# Macにインストールしたgitコマンドの実行時にパスワード入力を求められてしまう

Tags: macos, git

プログラミング初心者です。

gitをmacへインストールしましたところ、下記の通り、パスワード入力を求められてしまいます。

設定した記憶がなく、ここから先に進めないのですが、
解決策を教えていただけると助かります。

```
$ git --version

Agreeing to the Xcode/iOS license requires admin privileges, please run “sudo xcodebuild -license” and then retry this command.

$ sudo xcodebuild license
Password:
```

Answer (score 2):

ご自身のMacへのログインパスワードを入力する必要があります。
Macは一部のディレクトリーに特権がないと書き込みが出来ないディレクトリーがあり、「そこへ、（そのコマンドだけ）特権ユーザーとしてアクセスします。」というのが、`sudo`コマンドで、`sudo`コマンドはご自身のパスワード（Macのログイン画面で入力するもの）を要求してきますので、普段お使いのログインパスワードを入力すれば次に進みます。

Answer (score 0):

Mac のログインパスワードを入力してください。アカウントにパスワードを設定していない場合は、システム環境設定からパスワードを設定してください。

おそらく XCode Command Line Tool 版の git をインストールしたため、XCode の利用規約への同意を求められているのだと思います。

このため `sudo xcodebuild -license` (ハイフンが必要です) というコマンドを実行せよと言われていますが、この先頭にある `sudo` というのは「以下のコマンドを root 権限で実行してください」というコマンドです。

`sudo` を使う際に入力すべきはその Mac の管理者アカウントのパスワードです。git 特有のパスワードではありません。今回出ている出力を見る限り、ご自身の Mac アカウントのパスワードを入力すれば良いように見えます。

#### 参考

- [【 sudo 】指定したユーザーでコマンドを実行する](https://tech.nikkeibp.co.jp/it/article/COLUMN/20071205/288862/) -- Linuxコマンド集
- [ターミナルで sudo コマンドを使うには管理者パスワードが必要](https://support.apple.com/ja-jp/HT202035) -- Apple サポート